# difficulty in returning an array of class after being fetched from the server

Tags: ios, swift4

I am making a global function to hit the api and get response from the server. then that value is returned in the form of array of class but its returning nil when printing outside the data task the value is printed inside the data task

here is my code for the global function

```
    func fetchMovieList(url: String ) -> [movies]{
            var movie = [movies]()
            global.currentUrl = url
            // constant to store the url for nowShowing
            let convertdUrl = URL(string: url)

            // creating a Url session for fetching json from the server
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: convertdUrl!){(data, response, error) in


                // if request is error free then decode the json using json decoder and assigning the values to the array
                guard let data = data else {return}
                do{
                    movie = try JSONDecoder().decode([movies].self, from: data)
                    //movieList.comingSoon = movieList.nowShowing
                    print("\(movie)")

                }catch {
                    print("Error")
                }
                }.resume()
            print("\(movie)")
            return movie
}
```

Comment: The fetch completes asynchronously so you can't return data. You will need to pass a closure to process the data incentive it has been fetched

Comment: i am new to swift if you can help me with some code that i will be thankful to u

Comment: define the model of movies and load value in that model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("\(movie)")
```

This is returning nil because that line get executed before you have received any data from server. so movie will not be containing any data at that time. and once you get response from server, you store data in movie and then print it.

If you are facing issue returning data from this function you can use the code given in the below link. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49611494/9332509)